# How to tag a random user on a Discord server

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a bot that tags a random user with a string after running a command, but the bot keeps tagging itself every time the command is run.

```py
@client.command(aliases=['idea'])
async def idea(ctx):
    idea = ['idea1', 'idea2', 'idea3']
    usr = random.choice(ctx.channel.guild.members)
    await ctx.send(random.choice(idea) + ' a ' + str(usr.mention))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are running discord.py v1.5, please see [this documentation page](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html) on how to enable Privileged Intents for your bot.  This is a recent change that would explain why your bot cannot see any users other than itself.

Comment: Hey, Enabled privileged intents on the developer portal and also included them inside the bot and yet the bot is still only capable of recognizing itself and not any other member, I don't know if channel permissions have anything to do with it since the bot has administrator privileges, even tried to run the command in an event instead of the command decorator